Unable to import test cases in Azure DevOps using excel
While importing excel of test cases getting below error
Found field value error(s):
Forbidden work item type "Test Case" specified in column Work Item Type at line 5, column(s) 2.

I can reproduce the same issue when importing the test case in Boards -> Queries.

To export the test case work items to Azure DevOps, we need to navigate to Test Plan -> Test Suites -> Defined tab -> Import Test Case from CSV/XLSX.

Note: The import file(csv file) should include the following value(with the exact spelling):
ID: For new test case creation, leave this field blank.
Work Item Type: Test Case
Title: The title of the test case you want to create or update, which can be an alpha-numeric value.
Test Step: Can be empty
Step Action: Can be empty
Step Expected: Can be empty
You can use the option: Export test cases to CSV or  Export test cases to XLSX in Test Plan -> Test Suites -> Defined tab  to export the test case work items.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Import test cases

how can we import an existing test case with parent child relations via excel?

@Salman I am afraid that we are not able to import test case with parent child links. When we import test cases in test plan, it equals to create a new work item without any links. Only when we import the work items in Queries -> Import work items, it will include the related links. But the test case can not be imported in queries.  We need to manually link the work items after importing the test case in test plan.

I can fully understand your requirement. I suggest that you can create a suggestion ticket in this site: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest
